# how to set the port of snmp agentX subagent?

Tags: sockets, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am working on extending net-snmp to write a subagent with agentX.
Now I use the example codes from net-snmp, and compiled to a subagent.
Below is the codes I get from:
http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_MIB_Module

And I succeed to perform snmpget and snmpset to my subagent using agentX.

My questions:

1. I think the subagent and master agent are listening on a port, how can I find which port they are listening? I have been told the default port is **705**, but when I use "netstat", I can't find any process listening on port 705.
2. How to change the listening port of subagent? Do I need to change in the example code to set the port?

Answer (score 1):

By default, actually, on "anything but windows" the default is to listen to a unix socket located at `/var/agentx/master`.

You can change the listening address using the API suggested by the other poster, or even using the snmpd.conf configuration file:

```
agentXSocket tcp:localhost:705
```

When you create a subagent, it'll read your `FOO.conf` file where `FOO` is what you passed to `init_snmp("FOO");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved:
http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ%3aAgent_12

By adding 
netsnmp_ds_set_string(NETSNMP_DS_APPLICATION_ID,
                            NETSNMP_DS_AGENT_X_SOCKET, "tcp:localhost:705");

in the example codes before the 'init_agent' call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the snmpd.conf file

```
master agentx
AgentXSocket tcp:X.X.X.X:705
```

And in your agentx code write down these lines before `init_agent()`

```
netsnmp_ds_set_string(NETSNMP_DS_APPLICATION_ID, NETSNMP_DS_AGENT_X_SOCKET, "tcp:X.X.X.X:705");
```